# Integrating Over a Conditional Time-Dependent Region

Tags: numerical-integration, regions, physics, simulation

I'm experimenting with integrating over regions so I can check some physics simulations. Here's the rundown of what I'm attempting to do.

I have a rectangle that I'm rotating with a parameter:

```
m = 5;
g = 9.8;
l = 1;
h = 2;
θ0 = π/8;
Shape = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, h}];
RotShape[θ_] := Rotate[Shape, θ, {0, 0}];
```

Essentially, `RotShape[θ]` is a rectangle rotated around the origin by $\theta$. I'm then integrating over this region performing an angular momentum calculation:

```
α[θ_] := Integrate[m*g*x, {x, y} ∈ RotShape[θ]]/
   Integrate[m*EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ RotShape[0]];
s = NDSolve[{(θ'')[t] == -α[θ[t]], θ[0] == θ0, 
   Derivative[1][θ][0] == 0}, θ, {t, 0, 20}]
```

This has worked exactly as I expected. Here, I've been able to solve for the angular displacement of a rectangle rotating around the origin under gravity.

However, next I tried to alter my region. Rather than rotating freely, if the angle $\theta$ becomes negative I want the axis to switch to the other corner (to simulate the rectangle tipping back and forth).

```
BounceShape[θ_] := 
 If[θ > 0, Rotate[Shape, θ, {0, 0}], 
  Rotate[Shape, θ, {l, 0}]];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[BounceShape[θ], Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> 4], {θ, -π/2, π/2}]
```

The region looks exactly like I expect it to. I can even integrate over this region for fixed $\theta$. But `NDSolve` isn't liking it. No matter what I've tried, I can't get it to simulate this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Mathematica 12.2 doesn't evaluate your second code block

Comment: Your NDSolve command has wrong syntax.

Comment: @AelMinor `Rotate` isn't the correct command for your issue. Look for `RotationTransform` to rotate your region!

Comment: When we replace `Integrate` to `NIntegrate`, we cann't calculate `α[3]`

Comment: Although `RegionQ[Rotate[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, 2}], 3, {0, 0}]] == True`, but `NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] 
  Rotate[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, 2}], 3, {0, 0}]]` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

- Although `RegionQ[Rotate[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, 2}], 3, {0, 0}]] == True` but `Rotate` still not the right way to represent a proper region.
- Here we use `TransformedRegion` and `RotationTransform`.
- But the `NDSolve` still get som warning message,but I don't know how to rewrite it.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
m = 5;
g = 9.8;
l = 1;
h = 2;
θ0 = π/8;
Shape = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, h}];
bounceShape[θ_] := 
  If[θ > 0, 
   TransformedRegion[Shape, RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0}]], 
   TransformedRegion[Shape, RotationTransform[θ, {1, 0}]]];
Manipulate[
  Graphics[bounceShape[θ], Axes -> True, 
   PlotRange -> 4], {θ, -(π/2), π/2}];
α[θ_] := 
 Integrate[m*g*x, {x, y} ∈ bounceShape[θ]]/
  Integrate[
   m*EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ 
    bounceShape[0]]
Plot[α[θ], {θ, -(π/2), π/2}]
```

[image]

```
s = NDSolve[{θ''[t] == -α[θ[t]], θ[
     0] == θ0, Derivative[1][θ][0] == 0}, θ, {t, 
   0, 20}]

Plot[θ[t] /. s[[1]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]